# Finding the order of the pole of the complex function $f(z)=\frac{1}{\cos(z)-\sin(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am new to complex analysis , this was a example problem and the author just says that as $z=\pi/4$ an isolated singularity , it is clear that the order of the pole is one.

But I am not able to see why ? From what I understood , a pole of order one , means in the Laurent's expansion , the negative term's order is maximum of one .
How can one deduce the expansion from just looking at an isolated singularity

Comment: $\cos(z)-\sin(z) = -\sqrt{2}\sin(z-\pi/4)$.

Comment: I understood how $z=\pi/4$ is a singularity , I am not understanding how it became a pole of order one

Comment: What about $1/\sin(z)$ at $z=0$?

Comment: Just find its laurent expansion, if i'm not mistaken it should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}y}-\frac{y}{6\sqrt{2}} + \mathcal{O}(y^3) $, where $y=(x-π/4)$.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of Somos gives an elegant solution, but alternatively, let be
$$g(z) = \cos(z) - \sin(z).$$
$\pi/4$ is a zero of order 1 of $g$ because (check yourself)
$g(\pi/4) = 0$ and $g'(\pi/4)\ne 0$.